# Порядок подключения шрифтов в css через font-face

Tags: css, шрифты

Объясните, пожалуйста, правильный порядок подключения шрифта разного формата (eot, woff, woff2, otf, ttf, svg, local).

в основном порядок тот в котором я перечислил выше, но на https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/webfont-optimization?hl=ru порядок обратный.

вроде бы в итоге браузер выбирает только один формат, но влияет ли порядок подключения шрифтов на то, на каком шрифте он остановится?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Браузер отобразит первый поддерживаемый формат шрифта (на приведённом вами сайте есть эта информация). Так что порядок не важен. Ниже немного модифицированный вариант, взятый из спецификаций W3C:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FiraSansRegular';
    src: local('Fira Sans Regular'),
         url('/demo3/templates/nevado/fonts/FiraSansRegular/FiraSansRegular.eot'),
         url('/demo3/templates/nevado/fonts/FiraSansRegular/FiraSansRegular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/demo3/templates/nevado/fonts/FiraSansRegular/FiraSansRegular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/demo3/templates/nevado/fonts/FiraSansRegular/FiraSansRegular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/demo3/templates/nevado/fonts/FiraSansRegular/FiraSansRegular.svg#FiraSansRegular') format('svg');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Я использую его. Рекомендую также для прочтения [статью на htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/svoi-shrift-na-stranitse).

Comment: Иногда, svg-шрифт можно перенести перед woff шрифтом. Не все сторонние шрифты хорошо смотрятся и сглаживаются в хроме, а SVG-шрифты всегда отлично.

Comment: Не замечал, но не исключаю.